# “./file.py” VS “python file.py”

Tags: python, terminal, operating-system, editor

## What is the difference between the `./file.py` & the `python file.py` commands?

### What I See

I usually see people using `./file.py` when they are using a terminal-text editor like vim or nano or emacs OR when they are using linux based operating systems like Ubuntu or Arch Linux.

And I usually see `python file.py` from the ones who are using some other operating system. I’m probably not correct. But if it is so, what is the difference between the both?

Thank You!

Comment: The first one without `./` also works on properly configured Windows as it triggers a lookup in the registry for an appropriate program to run ".py" files. This is usually "py.exe" which interprets a shebang line or starts the default Python interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on linux-based operating systems, when you execute a text file, if it starts with #!/bin/python (shebang syntax), it will actually do /bin/python filename, so it is faster to do this than having to type python all the time, it is easier to make it an executable file, but there are no major differences

Answer (score 0):

In Linux and Unix operating systems, you can execute an executable (`./file.py`)  without explicitly specifying it as a python file, while you can as well execute same `file.py` as `python file.py` in both Windows and non-Windows Operating system.

For this python file to be executed without explicitly prefixing python to it, it must surely meet these two requirements:

**Must contain a shebang line**:
A sha-bang/shebang line is a line of code which consists of characters that tells the loader to use the specified interpreter, just as stated in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines)

> If the first line of a script file starts with #!, it is known as a
> “shebang” line. Linux and other Unix like operating systems have
> native support for such lines and they are commonly used on such
> systems to indicate how a script should be executed. This launcher
> allows the same facilities to be used with Python scripts on Windows
> and the examples above demonstrate their use.
>
> To allow shebang lines in Python scripts to be portable between Unix
> and Windows, this launcher supports a number of ‘virtual’ commands to
> specify which interpreter to use. The supported virtual commands are:
>
> ```
>     /usr/bin/env python
>     /usr/bin/python
>     /usr/local/bin/python
>     python
> ```

**Must be an executable file**

In Linux and Unix OS, files are treated separately depending on their permissions and mode, you must make `file.py` an executable before calling it without explictly prefixing `python/python3`, to make `file.py` executable, you need to change the mode to an executable by running `chmod +x file.py` from the file directory in Linux terminal.